# How to delete columns from multiple transformation in informatica in one shot

Tags: informatica

Is there a way to delete column names which are present in multiple transformation in one go?

I have deleted few columns at table level and re imported the same to informatica. By doing this columns from source and target will be deleted but not in the intermediate transformation.

Just like propagate attributes where in we can change the datatype in one go...don't we have anything which deletes the columns in mapping in one shot.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. But, I agree it would have been useful to have an option to remove unused columns automatically.

Comment: There is no such feature. If you need to remove these ports from a big number of transformation, you could (1) export the mapping, (2) edit the XML file, (3) import back the modified definition.